# Why is my homepage being set to a specific url instead of the usual '/'?

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I'm working on this app, and while I was debugging I noticed that whenever I physically refresh the page and on the initial load of the app, the default homepage seems to be routing to the `/search` route. Instead, I'd like for the homepage to be set to the `/` route by default; any ideas as to where in the app to look for this bug/how to set the `/` route to be the default homepage?

Here is my `app.js` file with all the routes (this is the `app.js` file in the `frontend folder):

```
const App = () => (
    <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Modal />
        <NavBarContainer />

        <div className="app-main-content-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SpotIndex} />
            <Route exact path="/spots/:spotId" component={SpotDetail} />
            <Route exact path="/search" component={SearchContainer} />
          </Switch> 
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

Here is my `app.js` that's in the root directory (outside of the `frontend` folder):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const path = require('path');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
const spots = require('./routes/api/spots');

// Loading static build folder for production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
}

// Using mongoose to connect to Mongo database with success and error messages
mongoose
    .connect(db, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB successfully'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Respond to JSON requests and requests from other software (i.e. Postman)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Uses the right port when in development and in production
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`));

// Requests for these routes uses the specified callback function
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/spots', spots);

// Middleware for Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

// Configuration file for Passport
require('./config/passport')(passport);

// Route for serving static assets
// Makes content under the public directory accessible
// i.e. In components, <img src='/images/splash.jpg' />
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

**UPDATE:**
I just tried changing the home route (the `/` route) to:
`<Route path="/" component... />` and the homepage did become the right one, but I don't think that'll work because then the `SpotIndex` component will always render on every other webpage.

Comment: Do you have another redirect in another file? I'd try searching for `search` and see what references come up.

Comment: @waz Ah ok, thank you for the advice! I'll look into that; it'll be tough since another person wrote that section of the code but hopefully it's not too hard to spot!

Answer (score 0):

just need to refactor `app.js` in front-end like so :

```
const App = () => (
    <div className="app-wrapper">
        <Modal />
        <NavBarContainer />

        <div className="app-main-content-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SpotIndex} />
            <Route path="/spots/:spotId" component={SpotDetail} />
            <Route path="/search" component={SearchContainer} />
          </Switch> 
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

now your default homepage will be `/`

Comment: Not sure this would make any difference. Because now you are taking away the exact path match for `/search` as well. And that can be an exact match as well. You would need `exact` on for the `path="/"` but taking it away from the others won't affect the result.